# Qual a diferença de uso de return false, event.stopPropagation() e event.preventDefault()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, manipulador-de-evento

Num *handler* de evento do jQuery, pode-se usar `return false`, `event.stopPropagation()` e `event.preventDefault()` (ou combinações desses) para "cancelar a ação" do evento.

Sei que tem diferença no comportamento deles, mas sinceramente sempre que preciso fazer algo do tipo, começo com `return false` e vou na tentativa e erro, porque ainda não compreendo muito bem a diferença.

Já li em algum lugar que `return false` é a mesma coisa que acionar `event.stopPropagation()` e `event.preventDefault()` ambos e já li gente dizendo que não é bem assim.

Alguém pode explicar melhor como devo fazer pra decidir qual desses caras eu preciso, com exemplos?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Retornar `false` em um handler de evento do jQuery é a mesma coisa que chamar `event.preventDefault()` e `event.stopPropagation()` (onde `event` é o objeto recebido como parâmetro).

Então:

- `event.preventDefault()` impede que o evento padrão ocorra (ex.: seguir um link);
- `event.stopPropagation()` impede que o evento seja propagado para os handlers dos elementos DOM pais;
- `return false` faz as duas coisas (e ainda interrompe a execução do handler imediatamente, sem executar as instruções que vêm depois).

(Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false)

Por exemplo, suponha que você tem o seguinte trecho de HTML:

```
<div id="main">clique<a href="teste">aqui</a></div>
```

E agora você instala dois handlers:

```
$('#main a').click(function(event) {
    alert('main a');
});

$('#main').click(function(event) {
    alert('main')
});
```

Ao clicar no link, os dois handlers serão executados e logo depois você será redirecionado para a página "teste" (esse é o comportamento default de um link).

### Usando apenas event.preventDefault()

```
$('#main a').click(function(event) {
    // impede o comportamento default (ir para página "teste")
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('main a');
});
```

Nesse caso, o `event.preventDefault()` impede de você ser redirecionado, mas o outro handler ainda será executado.

### Usando apenas event.stopPropagation()

```
$('#main a').click(function(event) {
    // impede de propagar o evento para os elementos pais (ex.: #main)
    event.stopPropagation();
    alert('main a');
});
```

O segundo handler não será mais executado, mas você ainda será redirecionado.

### Usando os dois ou com return false

```
$('#main a').click(function(event) {
    alert('main a');
    return false;
});
```

Se, no entanto, você chamar `event.preventDefault()` e `event.stopPropagation()` (ou, equivalentemente, apenas retornar `false`), o primeiro handler de evento será chamado mas, no entanto, o evento não será propagado para o segundo handler.

Pensando nos casos mais comuns, o `stopPropagation()` é útil para links, que têm um comportamento padrão associado, mas nem tanto para texto puro (afinal, o navegador não faz nada especial quando você clica no texto).

O `preventDefault()` é útil quando você tem diversos handlers e quer que um elemento tenha um comportamento único, sem herdar o comportamento dos elementos onde ele está contido.

Comment: Olá, Rodrigo. Então, já li essa resposta também, entendo que o comportamento deles é diferente, o que não está claro é o resultado de cada um, por isso pedi exemplos. Você poderia dar exemplos de quando é útil usar só stopPropagation ou só preventDefault?

Comment: @elias, adicionei um exemplo. Ficou mais claro?

Comment: Boa, ficou bem mais claro! Valeu! =)

Comment: Explicação perfeita!