# Item do menu ativo mas não funciona mais como link

Tags: jquery

uma pergunta básica sobre JQuery mas intrigante. O 'li' ativo em menu. 
Essa lógica que usei funciona. Porem, a tag 'a' perde sua característica principal que é um link para as outras páginas.

```
<html>
<head>
 <style type="text/css">
    li.ativa{ color:#f00; }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
  <ul class="menu">
   <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
 </ul>
</body>
</html>
<script>

$("ul.menu li:nth(0)").addClass("ativa"); //Primeiro item selecionado.
$("ul.menu li").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("ul.menu li").removeClass("ativa");
    $(this).addClass("ativa");
});
</script>
```

Comment: Esse HTML vem do servidor certo, podes fazer essa mudança de classe no servidor? ou então via url? senão tens de verificar no javascript o url com o link e é meio mau :)

Comment: Sáo links mesmo ou vc vai realizar a operação por jquery tb? olha [aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/oujjy7fp/) o exemplo que eu montei... veja se é isso

Comment: Sérgio. Quando removo o 'e.preventDefault();' os links âncoras para outras páginas voltam a funcionar, como você explicou. Só que perdem a propriedade 'ativa' quando clicamos em um deles.

Answer (score 1):

Isso acontece devido ao `e.preventDefault()` adicionado na função de *Callback* de *click*. Esse `preventDefault()` impede que o evento de clique execute seus procedimentos padrões, como o de submeter um formulário HTML, ou seguir o endereço de um link em um elemento `<a>`.

Mais sobre o preventDefault pode ser lido [aqui](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_preventdefault.asp). (Em inglês).

Answer (score 1):

Em seu script você está utilizando o [e.preventDefault();](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) que serve para impedir que o evento padrão ocorra, em seu caso, ir para outras páginas.

Para resolver este "problema", basta remover o `e.preventDefault();` de seu código, ficando assim:

```
 <script>
    $("ul.menuNovo li:nth(0)").addClass("ativa"); //Primeiro item selecionado.

    $("ul.menuNovo li").click(function(e){
        $("ul.menuNovo li").removeClass("ativa");
        $(this).addClass("ativa");
    });
</script>
```

Veja seu código em funcionamento no [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/randrade/bswv4mhf/3/).

[Nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/169/20615) você possui uma excelente explicação de seu funcionamento.

```css
li.ativa{ color:#f00; }
```

```html
<html><head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title> - jsFiddle demo by randrade</title>
  
  
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
  
  
  
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">
  
  <style type="text/css">
    li.ativa{ color:#f00; }
  </style>
  



<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
$(window).load(function(){
$("ul.menuNovo li:nth(0)").addClass("ativa"); //Primeiro item selecionado.
$("ul.menuNovo li").click(function(e){
    $("ul.menuNovo li").removeClass("ativa");
    $(this).addClass("ativa");
});
});//]]> 

</script>

</head>
<body>
  <p>Menu Redirecionando</p>
 <ul class="menuNovo">
   <li class="ativa"><a href="#item1">Item 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#item2">Item 2</a></li>
   <li><a href="#item3">Item 3</a></li>
 </ul>

<div id="item1">
    <h1>Item 1</h1>
    <p>Mussum ipsum cacilds, vidis litro abertis. Consetis adipiscings elitis. Pra lá , depois divoltis porris, paradis. Paisis, filhis, espiritis santis. Mé faiz elementum girarzis, nisi eros vermeio, in elementis mé pra quem é amistosis quis leo. Manduma pindureta quium dia nois paga. Sapien in monti palavris qui num significa nadis i pareci latim. Interessantiss quisso pudia ce receita de bolis, mais bolis eu num gostis.

Suco de cevadiss, é um leite divinis, qui tem lupuliz, matis, aguis e fermentis. Interagi no mé, cursus quis, vehicula ac nisi. Aenean vel dui dui. Nullam leo erat, aliquet quis tempus a, posuere ut mi. Ut scelerisque neque et turpis posuere pulvinar pellentesque nibh ullamcorper. Pharetra in mattis molestie, volutpat elementum justo. Aenean ut ante turpis. Pellentesque laoreet mé vel lectus scelerisque interdum cursus velit auctor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam ac mauris lectus, non scelerisque augue. Aenean justo massa.

Casamentiss faiz malandris se pirulitá, Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer Ispecialista im mé intende tudis nuam golada, vinho, uiski, carirí, rum da jamaikis, só num pode ser mijis. Adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

</p>
</div>

<div id="item2">
    <h1>Item 2</h1>
    <p>Mussum ipsum cacilds, vidis litro abertis. Consetis adipiscings elitis. Pra lá , depois divoltis porris, paradis. Paisis, filhis, espiritis santis. Mé faiz elementum girarzis, nisi eros vermeio, in elementis mé pra quem é amistosis quis leo. Manduma pindureta quium dia nois paga. Sapien in monti palavris qui num significa nadis i pareci latim. Interessantiss quisso pudia ce receita de bolis, mais bolis eu num gostis.

Suco de cevadiss, é um leite divinis, qui tem lupuliz, matis, aguis e fermentis. Interagi no mé, cursus quis, vehicula ac nisi. Aenean vel dui dui. Nullam leo erat, aliquet quis tempus a, posuere ut mi. Ut scelerisque neque et turpis posuere pulvinar pellentesque nibh ullamcorper. Pharetra in mattis molestie, volutpat elementum justo. Aenean ut ante turpis. Pellentesque laoreet mé vel lectus scelerisque interdum cursus velit auctor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam ac mauris lectus, non scelerisque augue. Aenean justo massa.

Casamentiss faiz malandris se pirulitá, Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer Ispecialista im mé intende tudis nuam golada, vinho, uiski, carirí, rum da jamaikis, só num pode ser mijis. Adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

</p>
</div>

<div id="item3">
    <h1>Item 3</h1>
    <p>Mussum ipsum cacilds, vidis litro abertis. Consetis adipiscings elitis. Pra lá , depois divoltis porris, paradis. Paisis, filhis, espiritis santis. Mé faiz elementum girarzis, nisi eros vermeio, in elementis mé pra quem é amistosis quis leo. Manduma pindureta quium dia nois paga. Sapien in monti palavris qui num significa nadis i pareci latim. Interessantiss quisso pudia ce receita de bolis, mais bolis eu num gostis.

Suco de cevadiss, é um leite divinis, qui tem lupuliz, matis, aguis e fermentis. Interagi no mé, cursus quis, vehicula ac nisi. Aenean vel dui dui. Nullam leo erat, aliquet quis tempus a, posuere ut mi. Ut scelerisque neque et turpis posuere pulvinar pellentesque nibh ullamcorper. Pharetra in mattis molestie, volutpat elementum justo. Aenean ut ante turpis. Pellentesque laoreet mé vel lectus scelerisque interdum cursus velit auctor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam ac mauris lectus, non scelerisque augue. Aenean justo massa.

Casamentiss faiz malandris se pirulitá, Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer Ispecialista im mé intende tudis nuam golada, vinho, uiski, carirí, rum da jamaikis, só num pode ser mijis. Adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
</p>
</div>
  




</body></html>
```

Comment: Removi o e.preventDefault(); e voltei a estaca zero. O item ativo não funciona mais.

Comment: O link está fazendo referência à que? Uma página `html`, uma `âncora`, um **site**?

Comment: Uma âncora no site.

Comment: Editei a resposta. Veja se lhe ajuda.

Comment: Funciona perfeitamente seu código. O meu não funciona. Estou usando require_once(toposite.php); e require_once(rodape.php); Só mudam o conteúdo das páginas. O link clicado não fica ativo usando o mesmo código lá.

Comment: Coloque seu `script` dentro da tag **body** e teste.