# Ajax não funciona no firefox e no chrome funciona

Tags: php, ajax, firefox

Estou dando um insert no banco de dados, no chrome funciona, no firefox minha requisicao não da sucesso. Alguém já passou por isso?

Troquei a função serialize() e passei os valores de forma invidual, para ver se era isso. Testei a passagem de cada valor, todos chegam na outra página o insert roda corrtamente. Só no firefox que não faz isso.

```html
$("#btnentrada").click(function(){
 var txtplaca = $("#txtplaca").val();
 var cmbtipo = $('#cmbtipo').val();
 var txtmarca = $("#txtmarca").val();
 var txtmodelo = $("#txtmodelo").val();
 var txtcor = $("#txtcor").val();
 var cmbcobranca = $("#cmbcobranca").val();
 var txtobs = $("#txtobs").val(); 
 $.ajax({
  url: 'insere_entrada.php',
  method: 'post',
  data: {'txtplaca': txtplaca , 'cmbtipo': cmbtipo , 'txtmarca': txtmarca , 'txtmodelo' : txtmodelo , 'txtcor' : txtcor , 
   'cmbcobranca' : cmbcobranca , 'txtobs' : txtobs},
  success: function(data){
   alert(data);
  }
 })
});
```

php

```
//verifica se as sessions estão preenchidas
include_once("status_logado.php");
require_once('db.class.php');
$placa = $_POST['txtplaca'];
//nao permite carcateres especiais
if ( !empty( $placa) && preg_match( '/^[\w\n\s]+$/i' , $placa ) ){
    $tipo = $_POST['cmbtipo'];
    $marca = $_POST['txtmarca'];
    $modelo = $_POST['txtmodelo'];
    $cor = $_POST['txtcor'];
    $cobranca = $_POST['cmbcobranca'];
    $obs  = $_POST['txtobs'];       
    $objDb = new db();
    $link = $objDb->conecta_mysql();
    $sql = "INSERT INTO TBL_COBRANCA (COB_PLACA,COB_MARCA,COB_MODELO,COB_COR,COB_OBS,ID_TIPO) VALUES('$placa','$marca','$modelo','$cor','$obs',$tipo)";  
    if(mysqli_query($link,$sql)) {
        echo "Dados inseridos com sucesso!";
    }else {
        echo("Erro na operação, contatar o administrador do sistema.");

    }

} else {
    echo "Só são permitidos letras e números";
    die();
}
```

Comment: Primeira coisa: já olho no console do navegador?

Comment: Testei o seu ajax aqui e funcionou, uso o `Firefox` como padrão

Comment: Relacionado https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/167/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você provavelmente está usando um botão submit para chamar o Ajax e não cancelou o evento. O Chrome fornece o objeto de evento no escopo global, mas o Firefox não.

Ao clicar no botão no Chrome, o Ajax será processado (exibindo o `alert`) e em seguida a página será recarregada submetendo o formulário. No Firefox isso não acontecerá e o formulário será imediatamente submetido sem processar o Ajax na função do evento.

Adicione o parâmetro `event` ao manipulador de eventos e cancele o evento com `event.preventDefault();`:

```
$("#btnentrada").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    ...
});
```

Outra diferença é que se você não fornecer o parâmetro `(event)` no manipulador de eventos, o `event` fará referência ao objeto de evento *nativo* do Chrome, que é diferente do [objeto de evento que o jQuery passa para o manipulador](http://learn.jquery.com/events/introduction-to-events/).

**Exemplo:**

```
$("#btnentrada").click(function(){ // sem o parâmetro event
    event.preventDefault();
    ...
});
```

Irá funcionar no Chrome, pois ele fará referência ao objeto de evento nativo que ele possui. Já no Firefox irá retornar o erro `event is not defined` porque ele não possui o objeto nativo.

Então é sempre bom usar o `event.preventDefault();` com o parâmetro `(event)` no manipulador, até porque se você quer enviar o formulário via Ajax, não faz sentido submetê-lo recarregando a página.

Comment: Perfeito! Muito obrigado mesmo. Cancelei o evento padrão do botão e funcionou