# Recarregar página php usando ajax com dados atualizados

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Eu uso o código Ajax pra fazer um post e atualiza um registro dentro do banco de dados. Depois disso eu queria carregar a página novamente sem recarregar a página. Se refere a uma tela de entrega de produtos. Quando clico no botão de entrega um label com a situação do produto mostra o texto "Em aberto" e depois que clico ele deve mostrar "Entregue". O processo de atualização no banco de dados funciona. Portanto só gostaria de mudar esse texto da situação sem refresh. Tem como fazer isso?

Código Ajax:

```
$(".tabela-detalhes").on("click","#botao-entrega-volume",realizaEntrega);

function realizaEntrega() {
  event.preventDefault();
  var compra = $(this).parent().parent().find("#compra").val();
  var sequencia = $(this).parent().parent().find("#sequencia").val();
  var volume = $(this).parent().parent().find("#volume").val();
  var dados = {
    compra:compra,
    sequencia:sequencia,
    volume:volume
  };

  $(".entrega-volume").attr("name","entrega-volume").attr("value",JSON.stringify(dados));

  $.post("controle/compras-volume-entrega.php",dados);    
}
```

Comment: Se um id é único, não faz sentido usar `$(this).parent().parent().find("#compra").val()`. Bastava apenas `$("#compra").val()`. Acredito que seu HTML seja inválido.

Comment: Acho que seu comentário não tem a ver com a questão, não é isso? Ou eu não entendi. Esse código funciona, já até utilizo na aplicação. O id é gerado dinamicamente dentro de várias linhas em uma tabela. Ai eu tenho que saber os valores de alguns inputs que estão alguns níveis acima no código da tabela.

Comment: Acho que vc não entendeu rs... Olha só, um id deve ser único na página. Por exemplo, na página não pode haver outro id `#compra`, então não faz sentido buscar parent() pra achar um id se ele pode ser achado diretamente com `$("#compra")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem alguns problemas que pude detectar no seu código:

- Falta o `event` como argumento da função:

  `function realizaEntrega(event) {`

Funciona sem? Em alguns navegadores funcionam (Chrome e Opera, por exemplo), mas no Firefox não, conforme abordado [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/318430/8063).

- Forma de selecionar os id's

Não faz sentido buscar um id. Conforme abordado [neste tópico](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/318255/8063), um id deve ser único, e se ele é único, não há necessidade de buscá-lo dentro de elementos. Basta acessá-lo diretamente com `$("#campo")`.

Provavelmente você está gerando uma lista de elementos com o mesmo id e está buscando esses id's em relação ao botão clicado. Funciona? Até funciona, mas é errado. Uma coisa funcionar não quer dizer que é o certo. O correto é trocar id por class, aí sim ficaria correto e não alteraria a funcionalidade do seu código. Basta trocar o `#` por `.`:

```
$(this).parent().parent().find(".compra").val();
```

Em relação a alterar o texto do elemento, como mencionou o Marcos, use o callback do `$.post` para buscar o elemento e alterar o texto:

```
$.post("controle/compras-volume-entrega.php",dados, function(data){
    var elemento = BUSCAR O ELEMENTO;
    elemento.text("Entregue");
});
```

Mas é bom enviar um retorno do PHP para saber que tudo deu certo, por exemplo, um `echo "ok";`. Isso porque, caso tenha dado algo errado, o callback será executado mesmo assim, e você vai sempre achar que deu tudo certo. Então:

```
$.post("controle/compras-volume-entrega.php",dados, function(data){

    if(data.trim() == "ok"){
       var elemento = BUSCAR O ELEMENTO;
       elemento.text("Entregue");
    }

});
```

No lugar de `BUSCAR O ELEMENTO` você deve selecionar o elemento que contém o texto, seja pela class ou outra coisa. Como você não postou o HTML na pergunta, não dá pra dizer como é.

Comment: Vou tentar usando o callback. Quanto a questão do id, acho que é só a semântica que está errada, não é isso? Eu só não quis mexer, pois já estava assim a muito tempo e funciona. Mas vou alterar aqui pra que fique certo. Obrigado.

Comment: É melhor deixar e fazer as coisas conforme as especificações para não ter dor de cabeça no futuro e ficar pior pra arrumar. Afinal, é tão simples rss.. basta trocar o # por ponto.

Answer (score 2):

No $.post, o terceiro parâmetro é um callback, que irá rodar após a requisição receber uma resposta

Tente algo parecido com o código abaixo:

```
$.post("controle/compras-volume-entrega.php", dados, function(response){
    //altera o texto.
    console.log(response); //irá imprimir no console o retorno da requisição
});
```

Comment: Mas no código php que insiro no banco de dados eu tenho que fazer algum código de retorno? Porque basicamente eu queria recarregar os dados da página sem dar refresh.

Comment: O seu código PHP deve possuir um retorno TRUE ou FALSE. Ou apenas 1 ou 2. No javascript a variavel response irá conter o valor que veio do PHP.