# Por que o event não existe dentro do bloco inferior?

Tags: javascript, javascript-eventos, escopo-de-variáveis, event-listener

Não estou conseguindo acessar o `event.target` dentro da função `setTimeout` no código abaixo.

```
const botao = document.querySelector('button');

botao.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log(event.target);
  setTimeout(function(event) {
        console.log(event.target)        
    }, 500);

});
```

Comment: Tente `this.event.target`

Comment: Ainda retorna como cannot get `target` of undefined

Comment: Pq o **event** dentro do `setTimeout` não quer dizer nada ali, não tem ligação alguma com o event do botão.

Comment: addEventListener('click', (event) => {o seu código...})  Faltou colocar como parâmetro do callback o event para o poder usar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O `event` é uma variável global `window` e só ganha propriedades dentro do *event handler*, como o `addEventListener`.

O `setTimeout` é uma função global que não atribui à variável `event` as propriedades do evento, logo, `event` isolado dentro da função do `setTimeout` não tem valor algum.

Mas antes é preciso saber que é sempre importante passar na função do *event handler* o primeiro parâmetro, que representa o evento disparado:

```
botao.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
                                   ↑
                               parâmetro
```

Isso porque versões menos recentes de navegadores (como o Firefox, por exemplo) não possuem a variável `event` nativa, ou seja, o primeiro `console.log(event.target);` já retornaria o erro `event is not defined`, conforme explicado [nesta outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/318430/8063).

Logo, ao passar o evento como parâmetro da função do `addEventListener` ela vira uma variável dentro da função e terá valor também dentro da função do `setTimeout`:

```js
const botao = document.querySelector('button');
botao.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  console.log(event.target);
   setTimeout(function() {
     console.log(event.target)        
   }, 500);
});
```

```html
<button>Clique</button>
```

Por outro lado, se você não passar o evento como parâmetro do `addEventListener` (o que não é recomendado, conforme expliquei mais acima), você poderia enviar a variável `event` para a função do `setTimeout` da seguinte forma, colocando `event` após o tempo de `500`:

```js
const botao = document.querySelector('button');
botao.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log(event.target);
   setTimeout(function(event) {
     console.log(event.target)        
   }, 500, event);
});
```

```html
<button>Clique</button>
```

Comment: Eu entendo que ele tenha que ser passado como parâmetro da função para existir dentro do setTimeout, mas mesmo sem passar, ele é mostrado na linha superior então porque ele  não é mostrado dentro do setTimeout?

Comment: @Sam Não entendi sua resposta, se der **console.log(e)** dentro do **setTimeout** retorna `undefined`, ou seja, não está fazendo nada ali

Comment: Rsrs.. peraí que vou corrigir

Comment: sim, no setTimeout é uma função sem parâmetros rsrsrs

Answer (score 4):

São eventos diferentes. O primeiro é o evento de clique, o segundo é evento do *timeout*; o segundo não possui um *target*, apenas o primeiro.

O que você está fazendo é o que chamamos de *closure*, onde uma função é definida com base no escopo atual da definição.

- [Como funcionam Closures em JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1859/5878)

Para que funcione da maneira que você deseja, você deverá manter uma referência ao alvo do evento do clique em uma variável no mesmo contexto em que define a *closure*:

```js
const botao = document.querySelector('button');

botao.addEventListener('click', event => {
  // Aqui, event refere-se ao evento do clique
  const target = event.target;
  
  setTimeout(function(event) {
      // Aqui, event refere-se ao evento do timeout
      console.log(target)        
  }, 500);
});
```

```html
<button>Pressione-me</button>
```

Veja que `target` foi definido como referência ao *target* do evento do clique e utilizado dentro da *closure*.