# Porque passar como parâmetro o event em uma função?

Tags: javascript

Tenho essa dúvida faz tempo, mas estou postando ela agora. Já vi várias vezes em códigos os programadores usarem como parâmetro em funções o `event` e sempre me pergunto se tem alguma relevância em usá-lo como parâmetro porque no final das contas o resultado será sempre o mesmo.

No exemplo abaixo ao clicar no primeiro parágrafo é executado a ação padrão do `contextmenu` que é exibir o menu de contexto padrão do navegador e quando clicar no segundo parágrafo é cancelado a ação padrão do `contextmenu`:

**Exemplo:**

```html
<p>Parágrafo 1</p>
<p id="p2">Parágrafo 2</p>
  
<script>
    let p2 = document.querySelector("#p2");

    p2.addEventListener("contextmenu", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();  
    });
</script>
```

Mas se eu retirar o `event` o código vai funcionar eu falo isso porque não vi nenhuma diferença ocorrer:

```html
<p>Parágrafo 1</p>
<p id="p2">Parágrafo 2</p>

<script>
    let p2 = document.querySelector("#p2");

    p2.addEventListener("contextmenu", function() {
        event.preventDefault();  
    });
</script>
```

Não estou me referindo o que é o `event` e sim o porque de usar o `event` nos parâmetros da função? que nem nos exemplos acima que é comumente encontrado em códigos de terceiros?

Comment: só faz sentido ter o event se vai usar, senão não precisa. Nesse caso, como disse que sabe o que é o event, ele está cancelando a ação desse evento, mas se não for fazer isso não precisa receber ele na função

Comment: Mas então a qualquer momento eu não irei precisar passar ele na função já que o mesmo funciona sem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Os navegadores modernos (os atuais, inclusive o famigerado IE11) incorporaram o `event` como propriedade nativa do objeto `window`. Se você abrir o console e executar `event` irá retornar `undefined`, ou seja, ele existe. Se não existisse, iria retornar:

> event is not defined

Realmente hoje em dia parece não ser mais necessário utilizar o `event` como parâmetro (digo "parece" porque não testei em todos os navegadores atuais), mas eu acho recomendado sempre usar, porque navegadores, como o Firefox de pouco tempo atrás (menos de 2 anos, como [mostra este tópico](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/318406/8063)) não possuía o `event` nativo, e se você não o colocasse, iria resultar no erro acima.

Porém, esse parâmetro não necessariamente precisa ter o nome `event`, ou seja, você pode nomeá-lo com qualquer nome válido, ele é apenas uma variável que recebe o objeto do evento disparado. Por exemplo, poderia ser `evento`, `e`, `ev`, `a`, `b` etc., como você achar melhor no contexto do seu código:

```js
let p2 = document.querySelector("#p2");
p2.addEventListener("contextmenu", function(qualquercoisa) {
   qualquercoisa.preventDefault();  
});
```

```html
<p>Parágrafo 1</p>
<p id="p2">Parágrafo 2</p>
```

Comment: Obrigado! @sam resposta valiosa.

Comment: Valeu Jovem! Abs!

Answer (score 0):

O parâmetro **event** não é obrigatório, mas muitas vezes ele pode ser necessário. O que tem dentro desse parâmetro são dados relacionados a eventos do browser, como por exemplo  algo relacionado ao tipo de evento que foi disparado, tamanho da tela do browser, posição de onde foi clicado no navegador, etc. De forma geral é isso, espero ter ajudado.