# Indicativo de Carregamento no JS

Tags: javascript, html, requisição

Desejo que o seguinte indicador de carregamento :  `<li Carregando...</li>` apareça em tela no lugar de uma lista de elementos enquanto a requisição estiver sendo realizada. Este é o meu código :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UFT-8">
  <title> </title>
</head>
<body>

    <form id="form-usuario" onsubmit="searchUsuario()" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="user" id="usuario" placeholder="Informe o usuario do github">
        <button type="submit">Buscar usuário</button>
      </form>

      <div>
    <ul id = lista>

    </ul>
      </div>

  <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
  <script>

    //função para procurar o usuário
    function searchUsuario() {

      alert("searching...")
      event.preventDefault()

      let coleta = document.getElementById("usuario").value

      axios.get(`https://api.github.com/users/${coleta}/repos`)
        .then(function(response) {//caso o usuário seja encontrado...
          console.log(response)

          var nomes = []//vetor que armazenará os repositórios
          nomes.push(`https://api.github.com/users/${coleta}/repos`)//adiciona o usuário obtido na busca/pesquisa do usuário

          for (var i = 0; i<nomes.length; i++){
              var lis = document.createElement('li')
              lis.innerHTML = nomes[i]
              lista.appendChild(lis)
          }
          console.log(nomes)

        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.log(error)
          console.log("Este usuário do github não existe")
        })
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Como resolver isto?

Answer (score 1):

Após o `event.preventDefault()` coloque:

```
var carregando = document.getElementById("carregando");
if(carregando && carregando.length) carregando.outerHTML = '';
var lista = document.getElementById("lista");
var lista_html = lista.innerHTML;
lista.innerHTML = '<li id="carregando">Carregando...</li>';
```

A 1ª linha busca a `li` com a mensagem "Carregando..." pelo id `#carregando`. Na 2ª linha o `if` verifica se ela existe, e se existe, remove.

A 3ª linha atribui a lista a uma variável (você não fez isso. Estava puxando a lista direto, o que não é muito recomendado). a 4ª linha armazena o HTML da lista temporariamente à variável `lista_html`. E a última linha insere a mensagem na lista.

No `then`, antes do `for`, você reinsere o HTML que foi armazenado na variável `lista_html`:

```
lista.innerHTML = lista_html;
```

Desta forma, a mensagem de "Carregando..." será substituída pelo HTML anterior e o `for` irá inserir os novos itens.

Caso entre no bloco `catch`, coloque lá também o código que remove a mensagem:

```
document.getElementById("lista").outerHTML = '';
```

> **Observações:**

- Sempre finalize uma linha com ponto-e-vírgula `;`.
- No `onsubmit`, envie o `event` como parâmetro da função: `onsubmit="searchUsuario(event)"`.
- E na função coloque o `event` também: `function searchUsuario(event) {` (veja o motivo [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/437437/8063)).

Comment: O único porém desta lógica é que o vetor nomes se esvazia, fazendo com que a lista não tenha mais conteúdo a cada inserção.

Comment: Resposta alterada.